# PHP подскажите хорошую библиотеку для работы с сайтами(кликер)

Tags: php

Какой библиотекой лучше всего работать с сайтами(нажимать определенные кнопки на сайте по html разметке, возможность загружать файлы на сайт)?

p.s возможно библиотеки для python

Comment: php и нажимать кнопки на сайте ? библиотека по загрузке файлов ? чего ? может js + функция move_uploaded_file ?

Comment: @sousage1212 нажимать на другом сайте

Comment: @sousage1212 веб-бот